# how to filter model.find query results with model.populate query results in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

```
var UserSchema = Schema (
{
    android_id: String,
    rooms: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Chatrooms'}],
    location: {country: String, state: String, coordinates: { latitude: String, longitude: String}}
});

var RoomSchema = Schema 
({
    Roomname: {type: String},
    ids: {type: Array},
});


Users
    .find({android_id: {$ne: userID}, 'location.state': LocationArray.state, 'location.country': LocationArray.country})
    .populate({
        path: 'rooms',
        match: {'rooms.ids': {$nin: [userID]}},
        select: 'ids'
     })
     .exec(function(err, found) {
     })
```

I want to find all users excluding myself in a state and country where i'm not in an ids array with them. Is this possible with populate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope that this may help you.

```
Users
.find({android_id: {$ne: userID}, 'location.state': LocationArray.state, 'location.country': LocationArray.country})
.populate({
    path: 'rooms',
    match: {'ids': {$nin: [userID]}},
    select: 'ids'
 })
 .exec(function(err, found) {
 if(found){
      vettings = found.filter(function (doc) {
            return doc.ids;
        });
   }
 })
```

Comment: thanks,but  I was wondering if there was a way to further filter my `Users.find` query results with a `.populate` before I start to handle the array.

Comment: if that isn't possible I will use your method, Thanks.